# Difference between Faust vs Kafka-python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, faust

I could not find any answer to this: what is the difference between [Faust](https://faust.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [kafka-python](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python)?
Is there any pros/cons on preferring any one of them?
As I understand it:

- **Kafka** is written in **Java**, and **Kafka-python** is a **Python** client to communicate with **"Java stream"**
- **Faust** is a pure **"Python stream"**

So, if I plan to use only Python then Faust should be better choice and if I want to have wider compatibility ([Go, .NET, C/C#, Java, Python](https://docs.confluent.io/5.5.0/clients/index.html)) then use Kafka + Kafka-python?

Note: I am new to using Kafka and I am trying to understand the pros/cons of different solutions.

I would highly appreciate any advice!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As I understand it you use both with Kafka, and both from Python, but with the difference that:

- Faust is for **stream processing** (filtering, joining, aggregating, etc)
- `kafka-python` (just like [`confluent-kafka-python`](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python) also) is a client library providing **Consumer, Producer, and Admin APIs** for Kafka.

So you could easily use both, for different purposes, from Python.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me with clarification.

Comment: I'm new to this. Can you explain what is filtering, joining, aggregating in stream processing or provide any reference to understand? TIA

Comment: @MitulMandaliya [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7mGBxG2NhVQ) covers a lot of it, as does [this course](https://developer.confluent.io/learn-kafka/kafka-streams/basic-operations/#stream-operations)